# Full Calendar reduce the distance between date and day

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I am using Full Calendar in react. When I take week view this is what I get
[image: Week view]

But I want to remove the gap between the day and date in the heading
(e.g. FRIDAY DECEMBER 6,2019) I just want a single space gap after Friday. Can you help me with this. Below is my full calender code alone.

```
<FullCalendar
  header={{
    left: "prev,next today myCustomButton",
    center: "title",
    right: "month,listWeek"
  }}
  views={{
    listWeek: { buttonText: "Week" },
    month: { buttonText: "Month" }
  }}
  timeFormat="H:mm"
  plugins={["interaction"]}
  selectable={true}
  fixedWeekCount={false}
  defaultView={this.state.calendarView}
  navLinks={true} // can click day/week names to navigate views
  navLinkDayClick={this.dayClick}
  editable={false}
  eventLimit={2} // allow "more" link when too many events
  eventClick={this.calendarClick}
  events={
    aclCheck("EventView") && this.props.events && this.props.events.rows
      ? this.state.events
      : []
  }
  viewRender={(view, element) => {
    if (view.type !== this.state.calendarView)
      this.setState({ calendarView: view.type });
  }}
  showNonCurrentDates={false}
  dateClick={info => {
    alert("clicked " + info);
  }}
  select={(info, info1) => {
    this.selectedDate = { start: info, end: info1 };
  }}
  unselectCancel="button"
  unselect={() => this.props.selectCalendarDates(undefined)}
/>;
```

The below is the array I pass into it.

```
[
  {
    end: Moment {
      _isAMomentObject: true,
      _i: "2019-12-24 08:51 pm",
      _f: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm a",
      _isUTC: false,
      _pf: {…},
      …
    },
    end_time: "08:51",
    end_time_delimeter: "pm",
    id: 30136056,
    start: "2019-12-23 07:51 pm",
    start_time: "07:51",
    start_time_delimeter: "pm",
    title: "zzzzz"
  }
];
```

As required in the comment the full code (file) is as below.

```
class CircleCalendar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      events: [],
      eventSortMenuVisible: false,
      eventSortLabel: "Upcoming Events",
      calendarView: "month",
      loading: true,
      canRender: true,
      visible: false,
      unavailability: []
    };
    this.calendarClick = this.calendarClick.bind(this);
    this.dayClick = this.dayClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.init();
  }

  async init() {
    await this.props.listEvents({
      circle_id: this.props.circle.id,
      nopaging: 1
    });

    if (
      this.props.events &&
      this.props.events.rows &&
      this.props.events.rows.length
    ) {
      this.props.events.rows.forEach((item, index) => {
        item.start = `${item.start} ${item.start_time} ${item.start_time_delimeter}`;
        item.end = moment(
          `${item.end} ${item.end_time} ${item.end_time_delimeter}`,
          "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm a"
        );
        item.eventStartEditable = false;
        item.eventDurationEditable = false;
      });
      await this.setState({ events: this.props.events.rows });
    }
    this.setState({ loading: false });

    await this.props.getUserUnavailability({
      circle_id: this.props.circle.id,
      limit: this.state.limit
    });

    if (
      this.props.unavailability &&
      this.props.unavailability.rows &&
      this.props.unavailability.rows.length
    ) {
      this.arrays = [];

      this.props.unavailability.rows.forEach(item => {
        item.start = moment(`${item.start_date} 00:00`, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
        item.end = moment(`${item.end_date} 00:00`, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").add(
          1,
          "days"
        );

        if (item.cuk_unavailabile_users && item.cuk_unavailabile_users.length) {
          item.title = "";

          item.cuk_unavailabile_users.forEach((user, index) => {
            let name = user.cuk_user
              ? user.user_id && user.user_id === this.props.user.id
                ? `You`
                : `${user.cuk_user.first_name} ${user.cuk_user.last_name}`
              : "";
            item.title += `${name}${
              index === item.cuk_unavailabile_users.length - 1 ? "" : ", "
            }`;
          });
        } else item.title = item.reason.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, "");

        item.color = "#abaaaa";
        item.textColor = "#abaaaa";
        item.allDay = true;
        item.backgroundColor = "#F2F2F4";
        item.eventStartEditable = false;
        item.isUnavailability = true;
        item.eventDurationEditable = false;
        this.arrays.push(item);
      });
      await this.setState(prevState => {
        return { events: [...prevState.events, ...this.arrays] };
      });
    }
  }

  async calendarClick(date, jsEvent, view) {
    this.setState({ event: date });

    if (date.isUnavailability)
      history.push(
        `/circle/${this.props.circle.circle_slug}/calendar/unavailable-date/edit/${date.id}`
      );
    else {
      let event = await this.props.getEvents({
        circle_id: this.props.circle.id,
        id: date.id
      });
      return this.eventDetailModal.open(event, this.props.circle);
    }
  }

  async dayClick(date, jsEvent) {}

  eventSortMenuButtonClick(flag) {
    this.setState({ eventSortMenuVisible: flag });
  }

  async onSortEventButtonClick(label, value) {
    this.setState({ eventSortLabel: label, canRender: false });
    await this.props.listEvents({
      circle_id: this.props.circle.id,
      nopaging: 1,
      event_type: value
    });

    if (
      this.props.events &&
      this.props.events.rows &&
      this.props.events.rows.length
    ) {
      this.props.events.rows.forEach((item, index) => {
        item.allDay = true;
        item.start = moment(
          `${item.start} ${item.start_time} ${item.start_time_delimeter}`,
          "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm a"
        );
        item.end = moment(
          `${item.end} ${item.end_time} ${item.end_time_delimeter}`,
          "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm a"
        );
      });
      this.setState({ canRender: true, events: [...this.props.events.rows] });
    }
  }

  exportCalendar(values) {
    let data = { module: "events", ...values };
    this.props.exportData(data);
  }

  handleOk() {
    this.props.form.validateFields(async (err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        await this.exportCalendar(values);
        this.setState({ visible: false });
        this.props.form.resetFields();
      }
    });
  }

  handleCancel() {
    this.props.form.resetFields();
    this.setState({ visible: false });
  }

  showModal() {
    this.setState({ visible: true });
  }

  async onCreateEventClick() {
    await this.props.checkEventDraft({ circle_id: this.props.circle.id });

    if (this.props.eventDraft && this.props.eventDraft.id) {
      history.push(
        `/circle/${this.props.circle.circle_slug}/event/edit/${this.props.eventDraft.id}`
      );
    } else {
      if (this.selectedDate) {
        this.setState({ clickedCreate: true });
        await this.props.selectCalendarDates(this.selectedDate);
      }
      history.push(`/circle/${this.props.circle.circle_slug}/create-event`);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <main className="main-inner-wrapper">
        <Header page="calendar" id={this.props.match.params.id} />
        <EventDetailsModal
          ref={ref => (this.eventDetailModal = ref)}
          user={this.props.user}
        />
        <div className="main-right-container">
          <Modal
            className="simple-modal"
            title="Download Information"
            visible={this.state.visible}
            onOk={this.handleOk.bind(this)}
            onCancel={this.handleCancel.bind(this)}
            cancelButtonProps={{ className: "cancel-btn" }}
            okText="Download"
          >
            <Form layout="vertical" className="simple-form">
              <Row gutter={14} type="flex">
                <Col xs={24}>
                  <FormItem label="Password">
                    {getFieldDecorator("password", {
                      rules: [
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: "Please input the password!"
                        }
                      ]
                    })(<Input type="password" placeholder="Password" />)}
                  </FormItem>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Form>
          </Modal>
          <div className="circle-tabs-contents-wrapper">
            <Row gutter={16}>
              <Col xs={24} xl={16} className="grid-col-xxl-18">
                <header className="top-buttons-header">
                  {aclCheck("EventView") ? (
                    <Button
                      style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}
                      type="primary"
                      disabled={
                        this.props.circle.status === "expired" ? true : false
                      }
                      className="main-btn"
                      onClick={() => this.onCreateEventClick()}
                    >
                      <span className="icon-plus-round icon-block"></span>
                      <span className="text-block">Create new event</span>
                    </Button>
                  ) : null}
                  <Button
                    onClick={() =>
                      history.push(
                        `/circle/${this.props.circle.circle_slug}/calendar/unavailable-date`
                      )
                    }
                    className="widget-btn"
                    type="primary"
                    ghost
                  >
                    <span
                      className="icon-no-date icon-block"
                      style={{ marginRight: "10px" }}
                    ></span>
                    <span className="text-block">Manage unavailability</span>
                  </Button>
                </header>
                <div className="card-widget calendar-view-widget mb-1">
                  <header className="card-widget-header has-positioned-options">
                    <h3 className="title-text title-text-medium">Events</h3>
                  </header>
                  {this.state.loading ? (
                    <div className="loader-has-padding">
                      {" "}
                      <Loader />{" "}
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    <div className="card-widget-content">
                      <div className="c-fullcalendar">
                        <FullCalendar
                          header={{
                            left: "prev,next today myCustomButton",
                            center: "title",
                            right: "month,listWeek"
                          }}
                          views={{
                            listWeek: { buttonText: "Week" },
                            month: { buttonText: "Month" }
                          }}
                          timeFormat="H:mm"
                          plugins={["interaction"]}
                          selectable={true}
                          fixedWeekCount={false}
                          defaultView={this.state.calendarView}
                          navLinks={true}
                          navLinkDayClick={this.dayClick}
                          editable={false}
                          eventLimit={2}
                          eventClick={this.calendarClick}
                          events={
                            aclCheck("EventView") &&
                            this.props.events &&
                            this.props.events.rows
                              ? this.state.events
                              : []
                          }
                          viewRender={(view, element) => {
                            if (view.type !== this.state.calendarView)
                              this.setState({ calendarView: view.type });
                          }}
                          showNonCurrentDates={false}
                          dateClick={info => {
                            alert("clicked " + info);
                          }}
                          select={(info, info1) => {
                            this.selectedDate = { start: info, end: info1 };
                          }}
                          unselectCancel="button"
                          unselect={() =>
                            this.props.selectCalendarDates(undefined)
                          }
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              </Col>
              <Sidebar hideCircleOfCare={true} />
            </Row>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: show us the code how you implemeted it!

Comment: @ErtanHasani  This is the model array I am passing in it


[{
end: Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2019-12-24 08:51 pm", _f: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm a", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
end_time: "08:51"
end_time_delimeter: "pm"
eventDurationEditable: false
eventStartEditable: false
event_type: "single"
id: 30136056
start: "2019-12-23 07:51 pm"
start_time: "07:51"
start_time_delimeter: "pm"
status: "published"
title: "zzzzz"
}]

Comment: @ErtanHasani I have updated the question and added the file in it

Comment: For this I think you probably need to modify the fullCalendar source code for that view type, to change the layout it uses. Although you _might_ be able to do it by modifying the CSS or over-writing the HTML after it's rendered. Have you checked the rendered HTML to see how it is done, and see if you could amend it?

Comment: @ADyson greate thanks. I overwrote the CSS classes and it worked